# Let A be a proper subset of X and B a proper subset of Y. If X and Y are connected, show that $(X\times Y)\setminus (A\times B)$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I know that this question is already answered in the site but I did it in a different way but I don't know if it is correct.
My attempt:

Suppose that $(X\times Y) \setminus (A\times B)$ is disconnected.

Then there exist non-trivial (I know this because of $A \neq X$ and $B \neq Y$)  disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U \cup V = (X\times Y) \setminus (A\times B)$.

Then we know that $(U \cup V) \cup  A\times B = X\times Y$.
Let's call $C=U \cup V$ and $D=A \times B$ and by construction these are disjoint.

Then $C \cup D = X \times Y$ but that is a contradiction because $X \times Y$ is connected.

So $(X\times Y) \setminus (A\times B)$ is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work. $U$ and $V$ are open in $X\times Y \setminus A \times B$, but for a decomposition as you want you need $U\cup V$ to be open in $X \times Y$. And you also need $A\times B$ to be open in $X \times Y$, which can only happen if $A$ and $B$ are. And you are only allowed to use that $A$ and $B$ are proper subsets. You assume way too much, and even inconsistent things.